# C# LINQ query creating inefficient SQL compared to original query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm using EF 6, ASP.NET on Windows

I have this SQL statement which looks like this:

```
SELECT M.STMTDT, M.stmtno, ISNULL(SUM(M.PayAmount),0) as Fee, ISNULL(SUM(A.Amount),0) as Adjustment, ISNULL(SUM(M.PayAmount) + SUM(A.Amount),0) as Total FROM MainData M
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Adjustments A
    ON M.STMTDT = A.STMTDT AND M.stmtno = A.Stmtno
where M.CID= '334R' AND YEAR(M.stmtdt) > year(getdate())-4
GROUP BY M.STMTDT, M.stmtno
```

It's a pretty standard query which a group, join, where and sums. I would like to create the same query in LINQ but it is proving difficult to do so.

This is my LINQ query:

```
var fourYearsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year;

var dataWithoutGrouping = from m in MainData
                              where m.CID == "334r" && m.STMTDT.Value.Year > fourYearsAgo
                              join a in Adjustments
                                on new {m.STMTDT, m.Stmtno} equals new {a.STMTDT, a.Stmtno} into grp
                              from ja in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new {
                                                Dt = m.STMTDT,
                                                No = m.Stmtno,
                                                Fee = m.PayAmount,
                                                Adjustment = ja.Amount
                                            };

    var data = (from b in dataWithoutGrouping
                group b by new {b.Dt, b.No }into grp
                select new {
                   StatmentFee = grp.Sum(x => x.Fee),
                   StatementAdjustments = grp.Sum(x => x.Adjustment),
                   StatementDate = grp.FirstOrDefault().Dt,
                   StatementNo = grp.FirstOrDefault().No
                   }).ToList();
```

Which produces this SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = '334r'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 2014
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t3].[value] AS [StatmentFee], [t3].[value2] AS [StatementAdjustments], (
    SELECT [t6].[STMTDT]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t4].[STMTDT]
        FROM [MainData] AS [t4]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Adjustments] AS [t5] ON ([t4].[STMTDT] = [t5].[STMTDT]) AND ([t4].[stmtno] = [t5].[Stmtno])
        WHERE ((([t3].[STMTDT] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[STMTDT] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[STMTDT] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[STMTDT] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[STMTDT] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[STMTDT] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[STMTDT] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[STMTDT] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[STMTDT] = [t4].[STMTDT]))))) AND ((([t3].[stmtno] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[stmtno] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[stmtno] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[stmtno] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[stmtno] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[stmtno] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[stmtno] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[stmtno] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[stmtno] = [t4].[stmtno]))))) AND ([t4].[CID] = @p0) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t4].[STMTDT]) > @p1)
        ) AS [t6]
    ) AS [StatementDate], (
    SELECT [t9].[stmtno]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t7].[stmtno]
        FROM [MainData] AS [t7]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Adjustments] AS [t8] ON ([t7].[STMTDT] = [t8].[STMTDT]) AND ([t7].[stmtno] = [t8].[Stmtno])
        WHERE ((([t3].[STMTDT] IS NULL) AND ([t7].[STMTDT] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[STMTDT] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t7].[STMTDT] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[STMTDT] IS NULL) AND ([t7].[STMTDT] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[STMTDT] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t7].[STMTDT] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[STMTDT] = [t7].[STMTDT]))))) AND ((([t3].[stmtno] IS NULL) AND ([t7].[stmtno] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[stmtno] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t7].[stmtno] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[stmtno] IS NULL) AND ([t7].[stmtno] IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[stmtno] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t7].[stmtno] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[stmtno] = [t7].[stmtno]))))) AND ([t7].[CID] = @p0) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t7].[STMTDT]) > @p1)
        ) AS [t9]
    ) AS [StatementNo]
FROM (
    SELECT SUM([t2].[PayAmount]) AS [value], SUM([t2].[value]) AS [value2], [t2].[STMTDT], [t2].[stmtno]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[STMTDT], [t0].[stmtno], [t0].[PayAmount], [t1].[Amount] AS [value], [t0].[CID]
        FROM [MainData] AS [t0]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Adjustments] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[STMTDT] = [t1].[STMTDT]) AND ([t0].[stmtno] = [t1].[Stmtno])
        ) AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t2].[CID] = @p0) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t2].[STMTDT]) > @p1)
    GROUP BY [t2].[STMTDT], [t2].[stmtno]
    ) AS [t3]
```

As you can see this SQL is wildly inefficient compared to the original statement.

Please can someone help me convert my LINQ to produce the original SQL shown above.

Also, no I cannot use SQL for unexplained reasons, sorry!

**Edit**

Example data:

MainData:

StmtDate|                 |StmtNo     |Fee

---

2016-01-29| 00:00:00.000    |3124360    |25.00

2016-02-12| 00:00:00.000    |3124391    |50.00

2016-01-29| 00:00:00.000    |3124360    |600.00

2016-02-12| 00:00:00.000    |3124391    |75.00

Adjustments:

### StmtDate   |          StmtNo|           Adj

2016-01-29 |00:00:00.000    |3124360    0.00

2016-02-12 |00:00:00.000    |3124391    0.00

2016-01-29 |00:00:00.000    |3124360    120.00

2016-02-12 |00:00:00.000    |3124391    60.00

Desired result:

### StmtDate          | StmtNo    |Fee    | Adj   |Total

2016-01-29 00:00:00.000 |3124360    |25.00  |0.00   |0.00

2016-02-12 00:00:00.000 |3124391    |50.00  |0.00   |0.00

2016-02-19 00:00:00.000 |3124404    |600.00 |120.00 |720.00

2016-02-19 00:00:00.000 |3124405    |75.00  |60.00  |135.00

Comment: What framework (ORM) do you use that converts linq to sql?

Comment: Entity framework

Comment: What version of EF? What platform? what OS?

Comment: EF 6, ASP.NET, Windows

Comment: You mentioned that you can't use raw SQL, but have you explored using a view and including that view in EF?  If you've reviewed the execution plans and determined that you cannot get EF to be as performant as desired, a view gives you that control, and you still have the EF abstraction.

Comment: Long story short, it's because of a few extra where conditions which I can't implement using SQL. Eg - I need an if based on an external condition which can add on an extra where statement depending on the value

Comment: Do you have an example data and your desired result?

Comment: @reds Please see edit, it's difficult to add a table though so apologies for the bad formatting

Comment: Replace `grp.FirstOrDefault()` with `grp.Key` and try again.

Comment: Argghh. You're right it works perfectly. HOWEVER, because I know that VB.NET isn't popular on stack overflow I converted my question to C#(I prefer it anyway). Group.Key is throwing me a build error in VB.NET :(

Comment: main data and adjustment is different table?

Comment: @reds yes they are

Comment: All you want to do is you need to sum the fee field excluding zero content?

Comment: I need the other fields listed too

Comment: What is the result you got from your sample `var data`?

Comment: You can name the key in VB.Net:  `Group b By New With Keys = {Key b.Dt, Key b.No } into Group` and then reference `Keys.Dt` and `Keys.No`.

Comment: @NetMage You are correct, I am not too familiar with VB syntax yet. Thanks

Comment: Just a couple of quick comments: (a) Don't confuse ugly with inefficient. Did you profile the generated query to ensure it was inefficient? (b) If you're going to use EF, start thinking in terms of retrieving object graphs, not doing join operations. It might not be possible in your case but too often I see developers trying to recreate the SQL in LINQ instead of thinking about it a different way.

Comment: @CraigW The SQL was very inefficient leading to SQL timeouts due to the 2 FirstOrDefaults calling 2 selects for each result.

Comment: Not a comment on this, but on your regex question... try (?<!-)\d{1,15}\.\d{1,4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ivan in the comments I came up with this solution:

```
var fourYearsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year;

var dataWithoutGrouping = from m in MainData
                              where m.CID == "334r" && m.STMTDT.Value.Year > fourYearsAgo
                              join a in Adjustments
                                on new {m.STMTDT, m.Stmtno} equals new {a.STMTDT, a.Stmtno} into grp
                              from ja in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new {
                                                Dt = m.STMTDT,
                                                No = m.Stmtno,
                                                Fee = m.PayAmount,
                                                Adjustment = ja.Amount
                                            };

    var data = (from b in dataWithoutGrouping
                group b by new {b.Dt, b.No }into grp
                select new {
                   StatmentFee = grp.Sum(x => x.Fee),
                   StatementAdjustments = grp.Sum(x => x.Adjustment),
                   StatementDate = grp.Key.Dt,
                   StatementNo = grp.Key.No
                   }).ToList();
```

I just needed to use `grp.Key` as the `FirstOrDefault()` was creating a select for each record.

Also, here is the answer in VB(I translated my question into C# as VB isn't that popular here and I translated it back) if anyone needs it:

```
 Dim fourYearsAgo = DateTime.Now().AddYears(-4).Year

    Dim dataWithoutGrouping = From m In dbContext.MainDatas
                              Where m.CID = "334r" AndAlso m.STMTDT.Value.Year > fourYearsAgo
                              Group Join a In dbContext.Adjustments
                                On New With {m.STMTDT, m.stmtno} Equals New With {a.STMTDT, a.Stmtno} Into Group
                              From ja In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              Select New With {
                                                .Dt = m.STMTDT,
                                                .No = m.stmtno,
                                                .Fee = m.PayAmount,
                                                .Adjustment = ja.Amount
                                            }

    Dim data = (From b In dataWithoutGrouping
                Group b By grpKeys = New With {b.Dt, b.No} Into Group
                Select New With {
                   .StatmentFee = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Fee),
                   .StatementAdjustments = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Adjustment),
                   .StatementDate = grpKeys.Dt,
                   .StatementNo = grpKeys.No
                   }).ToList()
```

It generates this SQL:

```
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = '334r'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 2014
-- EndRegion
SELECT SUM([t2].[PayAmount]) AS [StatmentFee], SUM([t2].[value]) AS [StatementAdjustments], [t2].[STMTDT] AS [StatementDate], [t2].[stmtno] AS [StatementNo]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[STMTDT], [t0].[stmtno], [t0].[PayAmount], [t1].[Amount] AS [value], [t0].[CID]
    FROM [MainData] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Adjustments] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[STMTDT] = [t1].[STMTDT]) AND ([t0].[stmtno] = [t1].[Stmtno])
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE ([t2].[CID] = @p0) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t2].[STMTDT]) > @p1)
GROUP BY [t2].[STMTDT], [t2].[stmtno]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Result i got:

If you have already your `EF` for `MainData and Adjustment`

I created a list:

```
    List<MainData> mdata = new List<MainData>();
    List<Adjustments> adj = new List<Adjustments>();
    List<Result> resFinal = new List<Result>();
```

and the `LINQ`

```
var gety = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4);
            var res = from h in mdata
                      join j in adj
                      on h.StmtNo equals j.StmtNo
                      select new Result { StmtDate = h.StmtDate, StmtNo = h.StmtNo, Fee = h.Fee, Adj = j.Adj, Total = (h.Fee * j.Adj) };
            resFinal = res.Cast<Result>().Where(x=>x.StmtDate > gety).ToList();
```

The Final Class Holder as a Result

```
 public class Result
    {
        public DateTime StmtDate { get; set; }
        public int StmtNo { get; set; }
        public double Fee { get; set; }
        public double Adj { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
    }
```